# How to specify an empty object and then build into it

Tags: typescript

I am trying to split up a long function into separate files and the functionality is fine but I am curious about the best way to go about typing this. So I have a function that has a bunch of event handlers. I need to be able to reference them in different files to add and remove event listeners. So I figured I would build an object and I could just pass that around. But I run into the problem as when I initiate the object I have to type is a `Partial<MyHandlers>` but when I pass it into the function in the new file I have something like the following `const myFn = (handlers: MyHandlers) => {}` but I then get the following error:

> Argument of type 'Partial' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyHandlers'

So here is a quick example of how I am building the object:

Also here is a codesandbox in case anyone is confused about the following example [Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/populating-empty-objects-in-typescript-example-dyz4lp)

```
const handlers: Partial<MyHandlers> = {}

handlers.init = init(data, handlers)
handlers.kill = kill(data, handlers)
handlers.wheel = wheel(data, handlers)
handlers.pointerUp = pointerUp(data, handlers)
handlers.pointerDown = pointerDown(data, handlers)
handlers.pointerMove = pointerMove(data, handlers)
```

So in this example, you can probably tell that I am just importing a function that initiates each of the handlers by returning the handler function. I know that it at least used to be common practice to build objects by specifying an empty object and then populating it afterwards. I could type each function like `const myFn = (handlers: Partial<MyHandlers>) => {}` but then I would have to do a check and see if the handlers exist first like `if(handlers.wheel) wheel()` which is a bit annoying.

I can't do the following because I can't pass the handers object into the functions because it hasn't been initiated yet:

```
const handlers = {
  init: init(data, handlers),
  kill: kill(data, handlers),
  wheel: wheel(data, handlers),
  pointerUp: pointerUp(data, handlers),
  pointerDown: pointerDown(data, handlers),
  pointerMove: pointerMove(data, handlers),
}
```

I could make this into a class and then just pass in the `this` keyword as the handlers argument but it would be the exact same result that I have now but with much more syntax. I could go through and initiate the object with blank functions and then repopulate it, but that just seems dumb to me. And I could specify each of the function first as their own variable like: `const init = init(data, pointerUp, pointerDown, pointerMove, wheel, kill)` and then build the object like: `const handlers = {init}` but that seems annoying too. I can initiate it like `const handlers = {} as MyHandlers` but I'm not sure if this is good practice or not.

So my question is what is the correct way to go about building an object, where you specify an empty object and then build into it with typescript?

Hopefully I was clear on my issue. And thanks.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. You are assigning to a property of an object the result of calling a completely different function using the object as an argument? There's no way to square a circle.

Comment: @JaredSmith what are you confused about not sure what the square a circle comment is all about. I need a way to reference the functions in different files so I can add and remove event listeners. So I am stating an object and then populating it with functions. Then I am using that object to reference the functions. The functionality is not the issue. It's the typing. Like I said you used to see this type of object building a lot but I'm not sure how to go about typing this.

Comment: The answer here is going to depend _a lot_ on how much you can constrain the implementation of `init(data, handlers)`.  For example, `const init => (data: unknown, handlers: MyHandlers) => function theRealInitMethod() { /* todo: actually fill this out */ };` would work _just fine_ with `handlers` only being populated with methods in the manner you lay out.

Comment: Further, do you need to make sure that _consumers_ of this setup always provide the whole thing, or is it all right for _them_ to provide a partial implementation?

Comment: @SeanVieira I added a codesandbox that should explain the setup pretty well. The handlers object is basically just so I can reference the functions so I can add and remove event listeners in different files. The data is set up in a store and is really a non issue here. I believe that handlers object should be fully populated by the time it is ever used. Like I said in the question the functionality is fine it's just the typing. I am also not sure what the best practice would be here.

Comment: @user3331344 your functions that are accepting a `handlers` object are presumably expecting (depending on how you typed it) a *fully populated one*, which means you have a chicken and egg problem, and if they don't (e.g. all the properties are optional) then it's not clear that you have any problem at all (at least until you have to access those properties).

Comment: Thinking about this more, particularly about "I could make this into a class and then just pass in the this keyword as the handlers argument but it would be the exact same result that I have now but with much more syntax".  Would it work for you if you could have the smaller syntax, but you used `this` to access `handlers`?